# What would be the effect of adding small (~<10mm) lengths of conductor between a CPU's contacts and socket

Tags: cpu

[I am interested specifically in the case of state of-the-art consumer processors and motherboards]

To clarify what the setup might be in practice, imagine wires running vertically between each pair of contacts on the CPU and socket.

I don't have much expertise in this area, but these are the potential issues I am concerned about:

- The additional length of the conduction path from the processor slows down the speed of processing.
- The change in length of the conduction path means that the processor won't work at all as the devices are designed to operate with a specific length of conduction path.
- There is interference of some sort between the conductors running from the CPU to the socket.

In each case I am wondering if this is a problem and, if possible, what sort of effects would be observed.

Comment: The first question is, why would you want to do such a thing? The effects of simply extending the connections can be mitigated with careful engineering, but if you're planning to tap into those connections for some reason, that would cause major problems.

Comment: It's simply rising the CPU away from the socket slightly. I've been musing about some cooling solutions which this would make possible. There are other options, but I'm exploring different approaches.

Comment: what is the current rise time and socket leadframe thickness   10A/us??  10% of 10mm ?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I'm afraid I'm rather out of my depth. Electronics is not my main area of expertise. Your questions suggest my original question may not be well defined enough.

Comment: This affects delay and rise time of voltage and thus signal integrity. Start with any details on schematic and CPU

Comment: If the rise time is say 7% of the clock period then the effective bandwidth of that clock is 5x the clock frequency.  So what is the max. CPU external clock frequency you are considering? and what is the real rise time.

Comment: I would go ahead and give it low-to-zero chance of success without severe underclocking due to increased inductance and capacitance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CPU has several types of pins/signals:

- Slow signals like SMBUS, etc.

These wouldn't care.

- Fast signals like PCI-Express, RAM, etc.

These all use transmission lines, single ended or differential. Any impedance discontinuity in the transmission line would create signal reflections and corrupt signal integrity, so you would need to make a riser connector with controlled impedance. This can be done (and [it is  done](http://www.larsenassociates.com/ariesrftest.html)) but it will involve tiny high precision machined parts and **obscene prices** because this is a very low-volume, specialty custom product. Not to mention how crosstalk between nearby signals would be handled. Perhaps tiny coax pogo pins? Add an extra zero to the price.

- Power/Ground

These require extremely low inductance which is achieved by having literally tons of pins. Here's a random PC CPU pinout from the internets:

[image]

Enlarge it and look at all the supply and ground pins (anything that starts with "V"). More than half the pins are supply and ground, and this  adds to the cost.

Adding inductance (ie, length) would degrade power integrity.

These are the reasons why motherboard CPU sockets sit as low as possible on the board and keep the connections as short as possible...

So i would strongly recommend you find a cooling solution that doesn't require this. It is a lot easier to move heat up by a few mm (a 10 cents copper shim will do the job).

Comment: Are you trying to cool it with liquid nitrogen or something?

Comment: I'm not sure running liquid over the silicon chip would work as the surface area is quite small. Most waterblocks I've seen run the water through small fins to increase heat exchange area. Also non-conductive liquids (ie, not water) have much lower heat capacity so would need huge flow rates...

Comment: OK, vapor chambers are cool! How about using liquid metal thermal interface material on top of the silicon, then a vapor chamber? The evaporation is going to take place in the sintered copper inside anyway, which increases surface area...

Comment: @Tim I'd look at finding a way to seal your chamber around the edge of the CPU so that nothing is needed underneath...

Answer (score 3):

This would dramatically increase the inductance associated with each connection from the PWB to the chip. It would also increase cross-talk between data signals on those connections.

It wouldn't affect (much) the ability of the processor to continue to do computations at high rates.

But all interfaces to the outside world (for example to memory and any peripheral bus like PCI) would have to be slowed down considerably to be made to work. For example instead of accessing RAM at 200 million transactions per second you might have to slow it down to 10 million transactions per second or slower. And of course the existing memory chips aren't designed to work with those slow access rates.

Comment: Factor in the overshoot due to mismatch in impedance and this inductance, the CPU and surrounding chips probably won't last long

Comment: I wonder how much modern high speed bus training phases can compensate for that. Cpu sockets already add a bit

Answer (score 0):

If you can slow the output edges (output drivers) by 10:1, to perhaps 10nanoseconds, and you solder 0.1uF capacitors across all VDD/RTN pairs on this modern MCU, you might get away with this.

Comment: It's not a modern MCU, it's a modern desktop PC CPU